# Multiply equations in lists

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list = {x + 1, x - 3, {x - i, x + i}}
```

The last two elements should be multiplied. Desired output is:

```
{x + 1, x - 3, x^2 + 1}
```

I tried to no avail:

```
Apply[Times, list, 2]
```

Comment: Look up `MapAt[]`; combine with `Apply[]`.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to specify the specific place. I may have very different lists, so I am looking for a general rule.

Comment: ...then you might want to use `Position[]` also.

Comment: It would be nice to see how much general solution would you like to have because I'm afraid of wasting time giving you next suggestion which may not fit your needs. :)

Comment: Agreed, what is the general situation?  Do you want any sublist within `list` to have its elements multiplied?  The latter sounds interesting - you would have to selectively `Apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {x + 1, x - 3, {x - I, x + I}, {3, 3, 3}, a, b, {a, b, c, d}};

# /. List -> Times & /@ list

(*  {1 + x, -3 + x, (-I + x) (I + x), 27, a, b, a b c d}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list = {x + 1, x - 3, {x - i, x + i}} /. {x_, y_} -> x*y // Expand

(*  {1 + x, -3 + x, -i^2 + x^2} *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: That method's not robust: it will fail, on something like `{x + 1, {x - i, x + i}}`.

Comment: @murray  Right, unless we know that the OP lists are always more then consisting of two sublists (like in your counterexample). In that case the way I propose is most economical one.

Comment: @murray. Could always be made more robust with conditions on `x` and `y`; something like `/. {x_ /; Head@x =!= List, y_ /; Head@y =!= List} -> x*y`.

Comment: @march Right, thank you, I did not think about it.

Answer (score 1):

This will only replace the `Head` with `Times` for lists, nothing else,

```
list2times = If[SameQ[Head[#], List], Times @@ #, #] &

list = {x + 1, x - 3, {x - I, x + I}, {3, 3, 3}, a, 
   b, {a, b, c, d}};
list2times /@ list
(* {1 + x, -3 + x, (-I + x) (I + x), 27, a, b, a b c d} *)
```